# Git is not visible in Source Code Managment on Jenkins job

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I would like to set source code managment of my freestyle jenkins job.
I installed git plugin manually from git-client.hpi file. 
I restarted jenkins, set git path but I can not see git in the source code management list.
There is no internet connection in server. 
So any suggestion?
Thank You

[image: installed git path]

[image: git is not listed]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have got the [Git SCM plugin](http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin) installed, right?

Comment: Dear @Stuart i re-installed scm-api and git is in SCM list. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

[Git Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin) has 10 dependencies:

- [Promoted Builds Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Promoted+Builds+Plugin)
- [Credentials Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Credentials+Plugin)
- [Git Client Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Client+Plugin)
- [SCM API Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SCM+API+Plugin)
- [Mailer](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Mailer)
- [Token Macro Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Token+Macro+Plugin)
- [Matrix Project Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Matrix+Project+Plugin)
- [SSH Credentials Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SSH+Credentials+Plugin)
- [Parameterized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin)

make sure you have installed all the plugins.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. I checked all plugins mentioned above and those are already installed (also most of the Git plugins shipped default with the Jenkins)

I think you have to choose "Free style project" when you create a New Item in Jenkins. If you have selected the "Pipeline" or any other from the list that "Source code management" section is not available when we configure the project.

Answer (score 2):

I installed the "GitHub Branch Source Plugin",  then it appears

Comment: [Welcome to Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)! This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit or a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Install all the git plugins from jenkins plugin manager. Same goes for if any other version control system is missing.

Comment: Strange, I installed the Git Blue Ocean plugin and restarted Jenkins and now it appears.